# Can AsyncPoco support multiple results sets?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, petapoco

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576370/petapoco-multiple-result-set-support) shows that there is support for Multiple Results Sets from PetaPoco but I am using the asynchronous version (AsyncPoco) and I am unable to see such feature?

Comment: This feature is now [in progress](https://github.com/tmenier/AsyncPoco/issues/55). As a side note, while PetaPoco and AsyncPoco have the same origins, they've each sort of taken on lives of their own and should be considered different libraries. In other words, there's no active effort to ensure feature equivalence going forward - new(ish) features in one generally need to be requested in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like AsyncPoco doesn't support this. Note that AsyncPoco is a fork of PetaPoco, with a separate developer. Not everything in one makes it into the other.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will have to avoid using multiple result sets for the time being.